# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable

Tags: kotlin

У меня есть такой код:

```
tvCategoryNameItem.setOnClickListener {
            val color = (constraintLayout.background as ColorDrawable).color
            btnRemove.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            if (color == context.getColor(R.color.white)) {
                selectedCategoryList.add(text)
                constraintLayout.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_blue)
            }
        }

         btnRemove.setOnClickListener {
            selectedCategoryList.remove(text)
            constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.white))
            btnRemove.visibility = View.GONE
           }
```

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку один раз, кнопка как должна менят свой текст, но после второго нажатия выходит ошибка:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable
                                                                                                            at logins.adapter.CategoryAdapter$CategoryHolder.addSelectedCategory(CategoryAdapter.kt:51)
```

строчка 51 это:

```
val color = (constraintLayout.background as ColorDrawable).color
```

Если я меняю строчку:

```
constraintLayout.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_blue)
```

на:

```
constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.mycolor))
```

то все работает

Comment: А какой вопрос?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы когда я менял background на градиент, все исправно работало. То есть когда я ипользую обычный ресурс цвета у меня все работает , но когда использую градиент выходит ошибка

Comment: Перевод ошибки: "Тип `StateListDrawable` невозможно привести к типу `ColorDrawable`". Вы же сами говорите, что это градиент. Какой именно цвет вы ожидаете получить у градиента? У него нет какого-то определенного единственного цвета. Именно по этой причине у вас в коде проблема.